# HTML - Displaying a Custom Text/Image Instead of Source Code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning HTML, and I'm curious about something. Since browsers can show the source code of a website, is it possible to show some random or predetermined text/image etc. instead of source code?

For example in Chrome when right-clicked to a website, we have the option to display its source code. I want to show something other than the source code of the page when the previous action occurs. Is this possible?

I'm a beginner so go easy on me please.
Cheers.

Comment: You could obfuscate your code by using only ASCII characters. `<html>` becomes `&#60;&#104;&#116;&#109;&#108;&#62;` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. 
Imagine you would request a website by a simple command line tool like curl. All you would get is the source code. 
Chrome is only rendering the source code to a website, but the file remains to be code.

You could create a client (a browser liker chrome), that only shows the rendered page and has no functionality to display the code, though.

But you will never be able to prevent users to view the source code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to force to force the browser to render something other than text used to rendering website, with 1 small exception - comments. They will show text invisible to "normal people" browsing website, and if you insist on showing something extra, you can display something called "ASCII art" - like that:

```
<!--
  _    _      _ _       
 | |  | |    | | |      
 | |__| | ___| | | ___  
 |  __  |/ _ \ | |/ _ \ 
 | |  | |  __/ | | (_) |
 |_|  |_|\___|_|_|\___/ 
-->
```

It could be even images, you can draw something on sites like [THIS](http://asciiflow.com/)